# Suppose that $A_1\subseteq A$ and $B_1\subseteq B$, and that $A\sim B$ and $A_1\sim B_1$. Then $A\setminus A_1 \sim B\setminus B_1$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> For $A,B,A_1,B_1$ are infinite sets. Suppose that $A_1\subseteq A$ and $B_1\subseteq B$, and that $A\sim B$ and $A_1\sim B_1$. Then $A\setminus A_1 \sim B\setminus B_1$.

---

**My attempt:**

We denote $A$ and $B$ are equinumerous by $A\sim B$.

Since $A\sim B$, there is a bijection $f:A\to B$. Similarly, there is a bijection $h:A_1\to B_1$.

> From here, I don't know how to proceed to define a bijection from $A\setminus A_1$ to $B\setminus B_1$. I think the proof may require Axiom of Choice, but don't know how. Please shed some lights!

Comment: This isn't true

Comment: This is true for finite sets, but may fail for infinite sets.  From your question, we cannot see what sets you want to use.  Also we do not have the definition of the symbol $\sim$, so we have to guess from your attempted answer what it means.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm unable to understand what you meant by *what sets you want to use*. I denote $A$ and $B$ are equinumerous by $A\sim B$.

Comment: We do no know whether you want to do this only for finite sets.

Comment: @GEdgar i meant for infinite sets. I will edit to make this clear. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample.  Let $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ be the natural numbers, and let $\mathbb E = \{2,4,6,\cdots\}$ be the even natural numbers.  Then our counterexample is:
$$
A_1 = \mathbb N, \quad A=\mathbb N,\quad B_1 = \mathbb E,\quad B = \mathbb N .
$$
We have
$A_1 \sim B_1$ and $A \sim B$
but $A \setminus A_1$ is empty and $B\setminus B_1$ is the set of all odd numbers.